# Where can I find free open source dbexpress driver for mysql

Tags: database, delphi, driver, dbexpress

I need a dbx driver for mysql. It should be free. Open source is appreciated. (delphi 7+ and mysql 5+)

Answer (score 2):

check [this](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/delphi/dbexpress_and_mysql_5.html) out

DbExpress drivers for MySQL V5.0

The Borland-supplied dbExpress drivers for MySQL prior to Delphi 2007 only work up to version V4.0 of MySQL, even though version V5.0 is becoming increasingly popular, and V5.1 is now in beta. The Just Software Solutions dbxOpenMySQL5 drivers provide a drop-in replacement for the vast majority of cases, allowing easy transition to the newer versions of MySQL.
with LGPL licence

Answer (score 0):

I find this [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/open-dbexpress/) 
(In fact it is not really for MySQL but MySQL via ODBC and I never test them)

I also find [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-dbx/) but it seems not maintained...

But even if dbExpress can be Open source and Free, MySQL is only open source and free if...