# List of free dbexpress drivers for Delphi

Tags: delphi, dbexpress

Anyone knows/has a comprehensive list of free open source dbexpress drivers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Open-dbExpress](http://open-dbexpress.sourceforge.net) for dbExpress driver for ODBC

and [refer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872419/where-can-i-find-free-open-source-dbexpress-driver-for-mysql) for open source drivers for Mysql database

Comment: I'll have a try but ODBC seems rather ancient to me :). I am not sure it works for Linux part.

Answer (score 1):

For Firebird : 
[IBExpert Personal](http://ibexpert.net/ibe/index.php?n=Main.IBExpertDBX4Firebird) with nag screen

[UIB](http://www.progdigy.com/?page_id=5) components have one dbexpress for Firebird in UIB\misc\DBExpress